# How to offset items in a 4x4 grid using sass loop?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to create a 4 by 4 grid in css using this loop, but with little luck. The div named "holder" is 100% width and height. I want its children to all be 25% height and 25% width. How would you do that using this approach?

html

```
  <div class="holder">
    <figure data-partial="1">1</figure>
    <figure data-partial="2">2</figure>
    <figure data-partial="3">3</figure>
    <figure data-partial="4">4</figure>
    <figure data-partial="5">5</figure>
    <figure data-partial="6">6</figure>
    <figure data-partial="7">7</figure>
    <figure data-partial="8">8</figure>
    <figure data-partial="9">9</figure>
    <figure data-partial="10">10</figure>
    <figure data-partial="11">11</figure>
    <figure data-partial="12">12</figure>
  </div>
```

sass/scss

```
  figure {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
  }
  @for $i from 1 through 12 {
    figure[data-partial="#{$i}"] {
      width: ?;
      height: ?;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The real question, why are you using `position: absolute`? Why not make `holder` a flex or grid parent?

Comment: Im using absolute because of scaling reasons and positioning. lets say i want to remove one of the items, if i use grid it will not keep its size. with absolute i can leave it intact.

Comment: Why wouldn't the item keep its size in grid or flex? You can remove items and have elements keep ratio.

Comment: In this case, for many reasons. To describe the context will take too much time. Please see my question and how i want to approach it instead of trying to suggest other solutions.

Comment: The point of Stack Overflow is to provide you with the best solution. Your question does not contain the context, so of course we will see your question and provide alternative solutions. Some SO questions fall into [XY problems](https://xyproblem.info/). If you want/have to use `absolute` positioning, then we can help you with that - but you have to make it clear in the question itself - otherwise, you will get solutions that seem to fit what you are trying to achieve better.

Comment: Point taken! Got it figured out tho. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Post your solution as an answer, as this may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

grid seems to be what you need:

example if holder is laid on the window

- 4x3 (your HTML)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body,
.holder {
  /* size your holder the way you want or already have */
  height: 100%;
}

.holder {
  /* what you basicly need for 12 children 4x3 */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
/* show*/
figure {
  border: solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <figure data-partial="1">1</figure>
  <figure data-partial="2">2</figure>
  <figure data-partial="3">3</figure>
  <figure data-partial="4">4</figure>
  <figure data-partial="5">5</figure>
  <figure data-partial="6">6</figure>
  <figure data-partial="7">7</figure>
  <figure data-partial="8">8</figure>
  <figure data-partial="9">9</figure>
  <figure data-partial="10">10</figure>
  <figure data-partial="11">11</figure>
  <figure data-partial="12">12</figure>
</div>
```

- 4x4

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body,
.holder {
  /* size your holder the way you want or already have */
  height: 100%;
}

.holder {
  /* what you basicly need for 16 children 4x4 */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}


/* show*/

figure {
  border: solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <figure data-partial="1">1</figure>
  <figure data-partial="2">2</figure>
  <figure data-partial="3">3</figure>
  <figure data-partial="4">4</figure>
  <figure data-partial="5">5</figure>
  <figure data-partial="6">6</figure>
  <figure data-partial="7">7</figure>
  <figure data-partial="8">8</figure>
  <figure data-partial="9">9</figure>
  <figure data-partial="10">10</figure>
  <figure data-partial="11">11</figure>
  <figure data-partial="12">12</figure>
  <figure data-partial="13">13</figure>
  <figure data-partial="14">14</figure>
  <figure data-partial="15">15</figure>
  <figure data-partial="16">16</figure>
</div>
```

ressources:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids
- plenty more via your favorite search engines ;)